# how to write auto completion search by alphabet?

Tags: javascript, json, autocomplete

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Create a new variable j$ just to avoid any conflicts with other libraries which may be using $.
    var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
    //Capture the list of countries in a Array.
   var countryArray = {!jsonDescriptionData};
    //on Document ready
    j$(document).ready(function(){
        j$("#countryautocomplete").autocomplete({
            source:countryArray               
    });
    });        
</script>
```

Currently it is taking in this way. if i type "a' it is showing the names contain a.but i need in such a way that it has to show the names start by a. if i type ab .it has to show only names start with ab

Answer (score 0):

You need a custom matcher.  Only skim the API documentation to the end, to find exactly what you're looking for.

http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#example-1